# Can System.Web.Webclient Downloadfile allow a virus onto my filesystem

Tags: .net, antivirus

Using WebClient Downloadfile to retrieve a file from an external site, it has come to my attention that the external provider may not be using appropriate anti-virus measures.  I am using this in a .Net service...

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
  webClient.DownloadFile(externalURI, LocalFilePath);
}
```

When the Downloadfile method tries to write the file to the filesystem, does it get automatically scanned, and does the method throw an exception if the file is infected with something?  It may vary with different virus protection software, but my main concern is, does the .Net file I/O automatically get scanned, or do I need to add a virus checking layer to my code?

Comment: I know there is a Microsoft Antivirus API, but the intro documentation for it refers to Office 2000, so not trusting it to be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your antivirus. If the antivirus scans the file when the write-file call is triggered, it may or may not block your app. But i sugest you to put the file in a directory group marked as virus DMZ to know what to do with it.

You can configure your antivirus to asign a folder that will not check for viruses, and in that directory you can download the files.